# Creating a list of nested list in JSON with GSON Java

Tags: java, json, gson

Hi i am currently trying to read through a json file with gson using java and I am storing the values into lists which I can use later, but I am having trouble reading through a nested list. I want to be able to eventually want to make a **lists of lists for "drive"**

This is my JSON file called `test1.json`

```
{
    "pos":[
       {
         "x": 1.0,
         "y": 1.0,
         "theta": 1.0,
         **"drive":{
            "p": 1.0,
            "i": 0.5
         }**
       },
       {
         "x": 2.0,
         "y": 2.0,
         "theta": 2.0,
         **"drive":{
            "p": 1.0,
            "i": 0.5
         }**
          
       },
       {
         "x": 3.0,
         "y": 3.0,
         "theta": 3.0,
         **"drive":{
            "p": 1.0,
            "i": 0.5
         }**
          
       }
    ]
 }
```

This is my `PosData.java` file

```
package frc.robot.files.take2;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import java.util.List;

public class PosData {

    @SerializedName("x")
    private double x;

    @SerializedName("y")
    private double y;

    @SerializedName("theta")
    private double theta;

    @SerializedName("drive")
    private List<Double> drive = null;

    @SerializedName("p")
    private double p;

    @SerializedName("i")
    private double i;



    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public void setPartNumber(double x) {
        this.x = x;
    }


    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public void setPartType(double y) {
        this.y = y;
    }


    public double getTheta() {
        return theta;
    }
    public void setId(double theta) {
        this.theta = theta;
    }


    public double getP() {
        return p;
    }
    public void setP(double p) {
        this.p = p;
    }
    

    public double getI() {
        return i;
    }
    public void seti(double i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

}
```

and this is my main `JsonManager.java` file

```
package frc.robot.files.take2;

import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

public class JsonManager {

    @SerializedName("pos")
    private List<PosData> pos = null;

    public List<PosData> getPositions() {
        return pos;
    }
    public void setPositions(List<PosData> pos) {
        this.pos = pos;
    }


    public static String readFileAsString(String file)throws Exception
    {
        return new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(file)));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String file = "C:\\test1.json";
        String json = readFileAsString(file);
        System.out.println(json);

        JsonManager manager = new Gson().fromJson(json, new TypeToken<JsonManager>() {}.getType());

        List<PosData> posList = manager.getPositions();
        List<Double> xList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Double> yList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Double> thetaList = new ArrayList<>();
        **List<Double> driveList = new ArrayList<>();**
        //Confused of what to do with the list and how to loop through it
        

        for (PosData pos : posList) {
              xList.add(pos.getX());
              yList.add(pos.getY());
              thetaList.add(pos.getTheta());
              **driveList.add();**
        }

        System.out.println(xList);
        System.out.println(yList);
        System.out.println(thetaList);
        System.out.println(driveList);
    }
}
```

I have tried a few different things already but nothing has worked out yet, thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If you want `drive` to be a list of lists, why do you declare it a list of doubles (`List<Double>`)?  It should be `List<List<Double>>`.

Comment: SO how would I acces the values in drive since they are not being looped through by pos, sorry this might sound dumb but like what would i need to add in here                            
 ```for (PosData pos : posList) {
              xList.add(pos.getX());
              yList.add(pos.getY());
              thetaList.add(pos.getTheta());
              **driveList.add();**
        }```

Comment: is there a secondary loop that i would have to add?

Comment: To to through a list of lists, walk through the outer list in one loop to get each immer list, then walk through each of them. So yes, nested loops are required.

Comment: Java also provides streams for that purpose though. `outerList.stream().flatMap(List::stream).forEach(element -> {/*do something with the element (type Double) */});` allows you to walk through all elements comfortably.

Comment: so how should i use it in my case, when I try to do this ```for (PosData pos : posList) {
              xList.add(pos.getX());
              yList.add(pos.getY());
              thetaList.add(pos.getTheta());

              for(PidData pid: driveList){
                drivePID.add(pid.getP());
              }

        }```                      It gives me a null pointer exception but if I remove the parent list in the json file and the parent loop it runs fine how can i fix

Comment: @johannes-h do you have any idea why this happens, or how i can properly iterate over the second loop